# Trouble Webscraping seeking alpha

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am working on a script that uses python and anaconda virtual environments to webscrape seeking alpha follower data for particular stock tickers. I have asked questions on it before and the answers I have received have been helpful to a point. For some reason when I try to make alterations to ticker names, by adding more into the list or changing the names of the tickers, the code fails instantly, while other times it works fine. I am wondering if anyone has any advice/edits to be made for my code, or any other ways of going about getting this data. Attached is my code and output

CODE:

```
import requests
tickers = [ "atvi", "goog", "aapl", "amzn", "brk.b", "brk.a", "nflx", "snap"]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in tickers:
        r = s.get('https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data/{}?id={}'.format(ticker, ticker)).json()
        print(ticker, r['portfolio_count'])
```

OUTPUT:
[Here is the output error I receive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rer5I.png)

[Other times it works, this is how it should look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4xWH.png)

Comment: The error seems to indicate that you are trying to parse `None` to json. Some of the requests may not have any result. You should probably have something to check the response. `r = s.get('https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data/{}?id={}'.format(ticker, ticker))` `if r.ok: do_something`

Comment: It's also possible you're being rate-limited if you're running the script too often, or trying to load too many pages too quickly, making some of your requests return `None`. You can check the response code in your `get`

Answer (score 1):

If you put wrong ticker symbol or server has problems to serve your request, it returns empty answer and sets status code to something different than `200` (e.g. `403`). You need to check for that information:

```
import requests
tickers = [ "xxx", "atvi", "goog", "aapl", "amzn", "brk.b", "brk.a", "nflx", "snap"]

with requests.Session() as s:
    for ticker in tickers:
        response = s.get('https://seekingalpha.com/memcached2/get_subscribe_data/{}?id={}'.format(ticker, ticker))
        if response.status_code != 200:
            print(ticker, 'ERROR!')
            continue
        r = response.json()
        print(ticker, r['portfolio_count'])
```

Prints:

```
xxx ERROR!
atvi 84,194
goog 1,038,749
aapl 2,076,496
amzn 817,339
brk.b 198,362
brk.a 74,682
nflx 368,925
snap 95,903
```